# regex for comma delimited 6-digit values

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a validation javascript regex to check a string is a comma delimited 6-digit string. For example:

```
123456

OR

123456,123456,123456

but NOT

123456,123
```

The regex I'm using is `^([0-9]{6})(\,[0-9]{6})*`. The problem I'm having is how to get the regex to fail  on the last part, where it should fail since 123 is not a 6-digit number. I tired adding a $ to the end of the regex, but then it breaks the whole thing. Can someone help me so that the regex will FAIL unless the string is A) a 6-digit string or B) comma delimited 6-digit strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close but you needed a `$`:

```
^\d{6}(,\d{6})*$
```

Comment: I was using an online regex builder and when I added the "$" to the end it kept breaking, so I assumed it would break the code. I know see the regex builder needed the 'multiline' flag set as well for this to work as expected. Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
\d{6}(,\d{6}){0,}
```

In this page, it's work

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Edit my answer, `\d{6},?`match any group with 6 digits

Comment: the following sentences: 123456,666666,333333,444444 fail in second comma

Comment: ooh true, I forgot {1,}, `\d{6}(,\d{6}){1,}` now it should be work :)

Comment: it fails to select `123456` change it to  {0,}

Comment: @sven, `{0,}` is the same as `*` - also `{1,}` is the same as `+`

Comment: @pguardiario yes that's true hence why I asked him to change it because it won't select `123456` if he put * his answer will just look like your answer ;)